# Kali Linux Hashing Algorithm

Tags: linux, security, encryption, passwords

I'm a junior penetration tester student, learning many new things in cyber security and putting as much of it in practice as I can. I was practicing some hash identifying and cracking, and as I was taught, it's quite easy to identify hashing algorithms from their prefix:

```
$0 - DES
$1 - MD5
$2 - Blowfish
$5 - SHA-256
$6 - SHA-512
```

But when setting up a simple password on my Kali VM to attempt to crack it, I noticed the prefix doesn't match any of the above. No program or script used to identify hashing algorithms was able to identify the hash of my password. Anybody have a clue? My hash is:

```
$y$j9T$.sGz84zsn1z3EgwlRalxw1$zvcEB1MNuIc5G2dHb2MBp4jBiidw1F7MZQ33tgHaqV/:19343:0:99999:7:::
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *[yescrypt](https://www.openwall.com/yescrypt/),* a derivative of scrypt. See the [crypt(5)](https://man.archlinux.org/man/core/libxcrypt/crypt.5.en) manual page that's included with `libxcrypt` (which these days provides the crypt() password-hashing function in many Linux distros).

Original "DES crypt()" password hashes did not use any prefix like "$0$", as the systems at that time only supported the one type anyway. Only hash types added later use the prefixes.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to crack the password using John the Ripper with the format=crypt